# Get the keyboard height Using NSNotificationCenter, is not working in Swift 4.1

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a keyboard extension app and I need the height of the default keyboard.

To get height of the KeyBoard, I have tried dozens of solutions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27087733/8711985), but the Selector function never gets called.
Is there another way to find the height of default keyboard?

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/38653108/8711985] . here it is.

Answer (score 0):

This code will show the height of your keyboard -

```
func showKeyboard(notification: NSNotification) {
            if let sizeOFkeyboard = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
                let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working perfectly for me in **Swift 4.1**:

```
var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        // Register Notification, To know When Key Board Appear.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

        // Register Notification, To know When Key Board Hides.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)

        // De register the notifications
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

// MARK: - Keyboard Events

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
            keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        }
// use keyboard duration if needed (to animate your view)
        let keyboardDuration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double

    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {

        let keyboardDuration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double

    }
```

Comment: Again, I am working on keyboard extension. I have tried this method like a dozen time, it doesn't work.

Comment: hey did you find any other solution for getting keyboard height.